# Problems with audio

Tags: java, audio

everytime i try a suggestion someone has for making sound come to life when a button is pressed it never works. Even when I put the exact code they tell me. It's not just for this project but for a couple others that this has happend. 
Can someone please tell me how I would (in a way that actually works) make (i.e.) a beep sound when a button is pressed. If you want a specific button, try it with the button "Clear". Thank you for any help given!

```
package MorsecodeApp;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.awt.Scrollbar;
import java.awt.Point;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Morsecode extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField console;
    private JTextField english;
    private JTextField morse;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Morsecode frame = new Morsecode();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public Morsecode() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getImage(Morsecode.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/computer.gif")));

        setEnabled(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);

        Random randomnum = new Random();

        setTitle("Morse Code Translator - SwendiverDev1");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 532, 363);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        console = new JTextField();
        console.setEditable(false);
        console.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        console.setBounds(10, -4, 437, 37);
        console.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        contentPane.add(console);
        console.setColumns(10);
        String a = ".-";
        String b = "-...";
        String c = "-.-.";
        String d = "-..";
        String e =  ".";
        String f = "..-.";
        String g = "--.";
        String h = "....";
        String i = "..";
        String j = ".---";
        String k = "-.-";
        String l = ".-..";
        String m = "--";
        String n = "-.";
        String o = "---";
        String p = ".--.";
        String q = "--.-";
        String r = ".-.";
        String s = "...";
        String t = "-";
        String u = "..-";
        String v = "...-";
        String w = ".--";
        String x = "-..-";
        String y = "-.--";
        String z = "--..";
        String zero = "-----";
        String one = ".----";
        String two = "..---";
        String three = "...--";
        String four = "....-";
        String five = ".....";
        String six = "-....";
        String seven = "--...";
        String eight = "---..";
        String nine = "----.";
        String ten = "-----";
        english = new JTextField();
        english.setEnabled(false);
        english.setBounds(0, 30, 526, 43);
        contentPane.add(english);
        english.setColumns(10);
        english.setVisible(false);
        morse = new JTextField();
        morse.setEditable(false);
        morse.setEnabled(false);
        morse.setBounds(0, 148, 526, 43);
        contentPane.add(morse);
        morse.setColumns(10);
        morse.setVisible(false);
        english.setVisible(false);
        JLabel type = new JLabel("Type in the top box for it to translate in the lower one.");
        type.setEnabled(false);
        type.setBounds(0, 5, 526, 20);
        contentPane.add(type);
        type.setVisible(false);
        morse.setVisible(false);
        JButton A = new JButton("A");
        A.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".-");

            }
        });
        A.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".-");

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("You found an Easter egg!");
            }
        });
        A.setBounds(35, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(A);

        JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
        btnB.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-...");

            }
        });
        btnB.setBounds(113, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnB);

        JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
        btnC.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-.-.");

            }
        });
        btnC.setBounds(191, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnC);

        JButton btnD = new JButton("D");
        btnD.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-..");

            }
        });
        btnD.setBounds(269, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnD);

        JButton btnE = new JButton("E");
        btnE.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".");

            }
        });
        btnE.setBounds(347, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnE);

        JButton btnF = new JButton("F");
        btnF.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("..-.");

            }
        });
        btnF.setBounds(425, 55, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnF);

        JButton btnG = new JButton("G");
        btnG.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("--.");

            }
        });
        btnG.setBounds(35, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnG);

        JButton btnH = new JButton("H");
        btnH.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("....");

            }
        });
        btnH.setBounds(113, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnH);

        JButton btnI = new JButton("I");
        btnI.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("..");

            }
        });
        btnI.setBounds(191, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnI);

        JButton btnJ = new JButton("J");
        btnJ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".---");

            }
        });
        btnJ.setBounds(269, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnJ);

        JButton btnK = new JButton("K");
        btnK.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-.-");

            }
        });
        btnK.setBounds(347, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnK);

        JButton btnL = new JButton("L");
        btnL.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".-..");

            }
        });
        btnL.setBounds(425, 93, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnL);

        JButton btnM = new JButton("M");
        btnM.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                console.setText("--");
            }
        });
        btnM.setBounds(35, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnM);

        JButton btnN = new JButton("N");
        btnN.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-.");

            }
        });
        btnN.setBounds(113, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnN);

        JButton btnO = new JButton("O");
        btnO.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("---");

            }
        });
        JButton bringbackmorse = new JButton("Bring back the Morse code!");

        bringbackmorse.setEnabled(false);
        bringbackmorse.setVisible(false);
        bringbackmorse.setBounds(10, 312, 506, 23);
        contentPane.add(bringbackmorse);
        btnO.setBounds(191, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnO);

        JButton btnP = new JButton("P");
        btnP.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".--.");

            }
        });
        btnP.setBounds(269, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnP);

        JButton btnQ = new JButton("Q");
        btnQ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("--.-");

            }
        });
        btnQ.setBounds(347, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnQ);

        JButton btnR = new JButton("R");
        btnR.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".-.");

            }
        });
        btnR.setBounds(425, 128, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnR);

        JButton btnS = new JButton("S");
        btnS.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("...");

            }
        });
        btnS.setBounds(35, 167, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnS);

        JButton btnT = new JButton("T");
        btnT.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-");

            }
        });
        btnT.setBounds(113, 166, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnT);

        JButton btnU = new JButton("U");
        btnU.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("..-");

            }
        });
        btnU.setBounds(191, 166, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnU);

        JButton btnV = new JButton("V");
        btnV.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("...-");

            }
    });
        btnV.setBounds(269, 166, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnV);

        JButton btnW = new JButton("W");
        btnW.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText(".--");

            }
        });
        btnW.setBounds(347, 166, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnW);

        JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
        btnX.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-..-");

            }
        });
        btnX.setBounds(425, 167, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnX);

        JButton btnY = new JButton("Y");
        btnY.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-.--");

            }
        });
        btnY.setBounds(191, 204, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnY);

        JButton btnZ = new JButton("Z");
        btnZ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("--..");

            }
        });
        btnZ.setBounds(269, 204, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnZ);

        JButton button = new JButton("0");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("-----");

            }
        });
        button.setBounds(35, 240, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("1");
        button_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText(".----");

            }
        });
        button_1.setBounds(113, 241, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_1);

        JButton button_2 = new JButton("2");
        button_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("..---");

            }
        });
        button_2.setBounds(191, 240, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_2);

        JButton button_3 = new JButton("3");
        button_3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("...--");

            }
        });
        button_3.setBounds(269, 240, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_3);

        JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
        button_4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("....-");

            }
        });
        button_4.setBounds(347, 241, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_4);

        JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
        button_5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText(".....");

            }
        });
        button_5.setBounds(425, 241, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_5);

        JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
        button_6.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("-....");

            }
        });
        button_6.setBounds(113, 277, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_6);

        JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
        button_7.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("--...");

            }
        });
        button_7.setBounds(191, 276, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_7);

        JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
        button_8.setBounds(269, 276, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_8);
        button_8.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("---..");

            }
        });
        JLabel lightstxt1 = new JLabel("- When people use lights for morse code, long blinks are DAHS ");
        lightstxt1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lightstxt1.setEnabled(false);
        lightstxt1.setBounds(45, 42, 526, 14);
        contentPane.add(lightstxt1);
        JLabel chart = new JLabel("");
        chart.setEnabled(false);
        chart.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\SwendiverFull\\Morsecode\\bin\\learn.gif"));
        chart.setBounds(10, 80, 506, 243);
        contentPane.add(chart);
        JLabel lightstxt = new JLabel("and short ones are DITS");
        lightstxt.setEnabled(false);
        lightstxt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lightstxt.setBounds(126, 66, 250, 14);
        contentPane.add(lightstxt);
        lightstxt.setVisible(false);
        lightstxt1.setVisible(false);
        JLabel lblInMorseCode = new JLabel("In Morse Code dots (.) are called DIT and dashes (-) are called DAH");
        lblInMorseCode.setEnabled(false);
        lblInMorseCode.setVisible(false);
        lblInMorseCode.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
        button_9.setBounds(347, 277, 66, 25);
        contentPane.add(button_9);
        bringbackmorse.setVisible(true);
        bringbackmorse.setEnabled(true);
        JButton btnClickForMore = new JButton("Click for more about Morse Code");
        chart.setVisible(false);
        chart.setEnabled(false);        
        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("");



            }
        });
        clear.setBounds(446, -4, 70, 37);
        contentPane.add(clear);
        JButton sentence = new JButton("Write sentences and Translate!");

        sentence.setEnabled(false);
        sentence.setBounds(0, 0, 526, 25);
        contentPane.add(sentence);
        sentence.setVisible(false);
        btnClickForMore.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                btnClickForMore.setVisible(false);
                clear.setEnabled(false);
                clear.setVisible(false);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button_1.setEnabled(false);
                button_2.setEnabled(false);
                button_3.setEnabled(false);
                button_4.setEnabled(false);
                button_5.setEnabled(false);
                button_6.setEnabled(false);
                button_7.setEnabled(false);
                button_8.setEnabled(false);
                button_9.setEnabled(false);
                A.setVisible(false);
                btnB.setVisible(false);
                btnC.setVisible(false);
                btnD.setVisible(false);
                btnE.setVisible(false);
                btnF.setVisible(false);
                btnG.setVisible(false);
                btnH.setVisible(false);
                btnI.setVisible(false);
                btnJ.setVisible(false);
                btnK.setVisible(false);
                btnL.setVisible(false);
                btnM.setVisible(false);
                btnN.setVisible(false);
                btnO.setVisible(false);
                btnP.setVisible(false);
                btnQ.setVisible(false);
                btnR.setVisible(false);
                btnS.setVisible(false);
                btnT.setVisible(false);
                btnU.setVisible(false);
                btnV.setVisible(false);
                btnW.setVisible(false);
                btnX.setVisible(false);
                btnY.setVisible(false);
                btnZ.setVisible(false);
                A.setEnabled(false);
                btnB.setEnabled(false);
                btnC.setEnabled(false);
                btnD.setEnabled(false);
                btnE.setEnabled(false);
                btnF.setEnabled(false);
                btnG.setEnabled(false);
                btnH.setEnabled(false);
                btnI.setEnabled(false);
                btnJ.setEnabled(false);
                btnK.setEnabled(false);
                btnL.setEnabled(false);
                btnM.setEnabled(false);
                btnN.setEnabled(false);
                btnO.setEnabled(false);
                btnP.setEnabled(false);
                btnQ.setEnabled(false);
                btnR.setEnabled(false);
                btnS.setEnabled(false);
                btnT.setEnabled(false);
                btnU.setEnabled(false);
                btnV.setEnabled(false);
                btnW.setEnabled(false);
                btnX.setEnabled(false);
                btnY.setEnabled(false);
                btnZ.setEnabled(false);
                button.setVisible(false);
                button_1.setVisible(false);
                button_2.setVisible(false);
                button_3.setVisible(false);
                button_4.setVisible(false);
                button_5.setVisible(false);
                button_6.setVisible(false);
                button_7.setVisible(false);
                button_8.setVisible(false);
                button_9.setVisible(false);
                bringbackmorse.setVisible(true);
                bringbackmorse.setEnabled(true);
                btnClickForMore.setEnabled(false);
                btnClickForMore.setVisible(false);
                lblInMorseCode.setVisible(true);
                lblInMorseCode.setEnabled(true);
                lightstxt1.setVisible(true);
                lightstxt1.setEnabled(true);
                lightstxt.setEnabled(true);
                lightstxt.setVisible(true);// continuation of lightstxt1
                console.setEnabled(false);
                console.setVisible(false);
                chart.setEnabled(true);
                chart.setVisible(true);
                sentence.setVisible(true);
                sentence.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        bringbackmorse.setEnabled(false);
        bringbackmorse.setVisible(false);
        bringbackmorse.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                chart.setEnabled(false);
                chart.setVisible(false);
                console.setEnabled(true);
                console.setVisible(true);
                lblInMorseCode.setVisible(false);
                lblInMorseCode.setVisible(false);
                button.setEnabled(true);
                button_1.setEnabled(true);
                button_2.setEnabled(true);
                button_3.setEnabled(true);
                button_4.setEnabled(true);
                button_5.setEnabled(true);
                button_6.setEnabled(true);
                button_7.setEnabled(true);
                button_8.setEnabled(true);
                button_9.setEnabled(true);
                A.setVisible(true);
                btnB.setVisible(true);
                btnC.setVisible(true);
                btnD.setVisible(true);
                btnE.setVisible(true);
                btnF.setVisible(true);
                btnG.setVisible(true);
                btnH.setVisible(true);
                btnI.setVisible(true);
                btnJ.setVisible(true);
                btnK.setVisible(true);
                btnL.setVisible(true);
                btnM.setVisible(true);
                btnN.setVisible(true);
                btnO.setVisible(true);
                btnP.setVisible(true);
                btnQ.setVisible(true);
                btnR.setVisible(true);
                btnS.setVisible(true);
                btnT.setVisible(true);
                btnU.setVisible(true);
                btnV.setVisible(true);
                btnW.setVisible(true);
                btnX.setVisible(true);
                btnY.setVisible(true);
                btnZ.setVisible(true);
                A.setEnabled(true);
                btnB.setEnabled(true);
                btnC.setEnabled(true);
                btnD.setEnabled(true);
                btnE.setEnabled(true);
                btnF.setEnabled(true);
                btnG.setEnabled(true);
                btnH.setEnabled(true);
                btnI.setEnabled(true);
                btnJ.setEnabled(true);
                btnK.setEnabled(true);
                btnL.setEnabled(true);
                btnM.setEnabled(true);
                btnN.setEnabled(true);
                btnO.setEnabled(true);
                btnP.setEnabled(true);
                btnQ.setEnabled(true);
                btnR.setEnabled(true);
                btnS.setEnabled(true);
                btnT.setEnabled(true);
                btnU.setEnabled(true);
                btnV.setEnabled(true);
                btnW.setEnabled(true);
                btnX.setEnabled(true);
                btnY.setEnabled(true);
                btnZ.setEnabled(true);
                button.setVisible(true);
                button_1.setVisible(true);
                button_2.setVisible(true);
                button_3.setVisible(true);
                button_4.setVisible(true);
                button_5.setVisible(true);
                button_6.setVisible(true);
                button_7.setVisible(true);
                button_8.setVisible(true);
                button_9.setVisible(true);
                clear.setEnabled(true);
                clear.setVisible(true);
                btnClickForMore.setVisible(true);
                btnClickForMore.setEnabled(true);
                bringbackmorse.setVisible(false);
                bringbackmorse.setEnabled(false);
                lightstxt1.setVisible(false);
                lightstxt.setVisible(false);
                lightstxt1.setEnabled(false);
                lightstxt.setEnabled(false);
                type.setVisible(false);
                morse.setVisible(false);
                english.setVisible(false);
                sentence.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnClickForMore.setBounds(0, 312, 526, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClickForMore);

        lblInMorseCode.setBounds(45, 30, 482, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblInMorseCode);

        JLabel lblEe = new JLabel("ee");
        lblEe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                JFrame easteregg = new JFrame();
                easteregg.setVisible(true);
                easteregg.setEnabled(true);
                easteregg.setTitle("EASTER EGG");
                easteregg.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 500);
                easteregg.setResizable(false);
                easteregg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                easteregg.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
                JLabel ee = new JLabel();
                ee.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\SwendiverFull\\Morsecode\\bin\\th.JPG"));
                ee.setBounds(10, 80, 506, 243);
                easteregg.getContentPane().add(ee);
            }
        });
        lblEe.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        lblEe.setBounds(0, 245, 12, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblEe);


        sentence.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                btnClickForMore.setVisible(false);
                clear.setEnabled(false);
                clear.setVisible(false);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button_1.setEnabled(false);
                button_2.setEnabled(false);
                button_3.setEnabled(false);
                button_4.setEnabled(false);
                button_5.setEnabled(false);
                button_6.setEnabled(false);
                button_7.setEnabled(false);
                button_8.setEnabled(false);
                button_9.setEnabled(false);
                A.setVisible(false);
                btnB.setVisible(false);
                btnC.setVisible(false);
                btnD.setVisible(false);
                btnE.setVisible(false);
                btnF.setVisible(false);
                btnG.setVisible(false);
                btnH.setVisible(false);
                btnI.setVisible(false);
                btnJ.setVisible(false);
                btnK.setVisible(false);
                btnL.setVisible(false);
                btnM.setVisible(false);
                btnN.setVisible(false);
                btnO.setVisible(false);
                btnP.setVisible(false);
                btnQ.setVisible(false);
                btnR.setVisible(false);
                btnS.setVisible(false);
                btnT.setVisible(false);
                btnU.setVisible(false);
                btnV.setVisible(false);
                btnW.setVisible(false);
                btnX.setVisible(false);
                btnY.setVisible(false);
                btnZ.setVisible(false);
                A.setEnabled(false);
                btnB.setEnabled(false);
                btnC.setEnabled(false);
                btnD.setEnabled(false);
                btnE.setEnabled(false);
                btnF.setEnabled(false);
                btnG.setEnabled(false);
                btnH.setEnabled(false);
                btnI.setEnabled(false);
                btnJ.setEnabled(false);
                btnK.setEnabled(false);
                btnL.setEnabled(false);
                btnM.setEnabled(false);
                btnN.setEnabled(false);
                btnO.setEnabled(false);
                btnP.setEnabled(false);
                btnQ.setEnabled(false);
                btnR.setEnabled(false);
                btnS.setEnabled(false);
                btnT.setEnabled(false);
                btnU.setEnabled(false);
                btnV.setEnabled(false);
                btnW.setEnabled(false);
                btnX.setEnabled(false);
                btnY.setEnabled(false);
                btnZ.setEnabled(false);
                button.setVisible(false);
                button_1.setVisible(false);
                button_2.setVisible(false);
                button_3.setVisible(false);
                button_4.setVisible(false);
                button_5.setVisible(false);
                button_6.setVisible(false);
                button_7.setVisible(false);
                button_8.setVisible(false);
                button_9.setVisible(false);
                bringbackmorse.setVisible(true);
                bringbackmorse.setEnabled(true);
                btnClickForMore.setEnabled(false);
                btnClickForMore.setVisible(false);
                lblInMorseCode.setVisible(false);
                lblInMorseCode.setEnabled(false);
                lightstxt1.setVisible(false);
                lightstxt1.setEnabled(false);
                lightstxt.setEnabled(false);
                lightstxt.setVisible(false);// continuation of lightstxt1
                console.setEnabled(false);
                console.setVisible(false);
                chart.setEnabled(false);
                chart.setVisible(false);
                sentence.setVisible(false);
                sentence.setEnabled(false);
                morse.setVisible(true);
                english.setVisible(true);
                morse.setEnabled(true);
                english.setEnabled(true);
                type.setEnabled(true);
                type.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button_9.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("----.");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A helpful tip - the clear button is on line 607! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited code to work without javafx

```
clear.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                 // open the sound file as a Java input stream
                 String fileLocation = "";
                 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);

                 // create an audiostream from the inputstream
                 AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

                 // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
                 AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            }
        });
```

Do note if you want to use it like this, place the audio file in the root of you project and give String bip the name of the file.

Comment: I tried the code, it wanted me to change MediaPlayer to MediaTracker - also when I try to import Media for the line Media hit = new Media(bip); the first part gets imported correctly but then it says the second media, cannot be "instantiate". is it because I haven't changed bip to an audio file yet?

Comment: Apologies i used way that only works with imports from javafx i'll edit my code to work without javafx.

Comment: No problem, if this helped you, do you mind marking it is as correct?